# carousel slider "A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom." flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building a home page for that I have created a hidden drawer on a separate page and a home screen on separate and stack both 'hidden drawer & 'home screen on the home page and also created foldable search button on the home screen along with the menu button on the same row with margin:spaceBetween .
I have created carousel slider on a separate page for 2nd row on home page i.e. down below the search & menu button and call that carousel slider on home page but showing error

> "A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom"

And why is it on bottom when I tried to add it on top. I have tried every possible padding & spacing but nothing work, please help

**DevTools layout**
[image]

**Code of home screen**

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _folded = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/menu.svg",
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                child: Container(
                  width: _folded ? 52 : 250,
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(4, 0),
                        ),
                      ]),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                          child: !_folded
                              ? TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Search Book, Author,Genre ',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontFamily:
                                          GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: InkWell(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(32),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    _folded
                                        ? "assets/icons/search.svg"
                                        : "assets/icons/close1.svg",
                                    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(18),
                                    color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _folded = !_folded;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [ImageSlider()],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Code OF the carousel slider**

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            items: [
              //1st ImageSlider
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/13.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //2nd Image of Slider
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/15.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //3rd Image of Slider
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/3.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            //Slider Container properties
            options: CarouselOptions(
              // height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
              height: 50,
              autoPlay: true,
              reverse: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: remove ListView from CarouselSlider parent

Comment: Wrap CarouselSlider with Container and set a fixed height.

Comment: should i return a container instead of a scaffold and remove list view will work and how to set fixed height

Comment: not working still same

Comment: Does your `carousel slider` code snippet means `ImageSlider()`?

Comment: yaa i named it as ImageSlideer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Single child wrap with `Expanded(child: ImageSlider()),` and it will take extra spaces.

While using row

```dart
       Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // will take full spaces but width- IconSize
                  Flexible(
                    child: ImageSlider(),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

or just wrap with `SizedBox`

```dart
    SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                /// controll position
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: ImageSlider(),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

**Test Widgets**

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _folded = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            Row(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/icons/menu.svg",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                  child: Container(
                    width: _folded ? 52 : 250,
                    // height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(4, 0),
                          ),
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                            child: !_folded
                                ? TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Search Book, Author,Genre ',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54,
                                        fontFamily:
                                            GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                                      ),
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
                        AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                          child: Material(
                            type: MaterialType.transparency,
                            child: InkWell(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      _folded
                                          ? "assets/icons/search.svg"
                                          : "assets/icons/close1.svg",
                                      // height: getProportionateScreenHeight(18),
                                      height: 18,
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _folded = !_folded;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            //For Single, will take full spaces
            // Expanded(child: ImageSlider()),

            /// with  rows, could be use [Flexible]
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // will take full spaces but width- IconSize
                  Flexible(
                    child: ImageSlider(),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            /// or just wrap with SizedBOx
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                /// controll position
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: ImageSlider(),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Text("Extra Bottom Part "),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  ImageSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageSliderState createState() => _ImageSliderState();
}

class _ImageSliderState extends State<ImageSlider> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          items: [
            //1st ImageSlider
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                // image: DecorationImage(
                //   image: AssetImage("assets/images/13.jpg"),
                //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                // ),
              ),
            ),
            //2nd Image of Slider
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                // image: DecorationImage(
                //   image: AssetImage("assets/images/15.jpg"),
                //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                // ),
              ),
            ),

            //3rd Image of Slider
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                // image: DecorationImage(
                //   image: AssetImage("assets/images/3.jpg"),
                //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                // ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          //Slider Container properties
          options: CarouselOptions(
            // height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
            height: 50,
            autoPlay: true,
            reverse: true,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why expanded method takes width icon size and why you use icon.ac there and same in sized box what is its use can you please explain. and expanded method works exactly as you said icon size but sized box method got confined to very small space with that icon

Comment: your expanded method works well but when I even added imageslider inside animate container why its still not taking its color as bg and also there is a lot of blank space above which am not able to remove

Comment: i added emulator image too please have a look and reply

Comment: For Expanded, it will take available spaces and Flexible  controls how a child should be flexes. You try using `Column<Flex<v:2>,<Flex<v:4>>>` or just wrap with Flexible and use `flex:x` on row's children.  You will get idea how it works. 
Wrapping Row with Expanded we are telling it to take as much Space as Possible and then same for the inner child. Because of our `Expnaded` taking rest of the spaces(providing space for icon), we can't see our  BGcolor.
. But you can choose `SizedBox` for height and provide flex or row's children for width...(I think)

Comment: For Background color, you need to provide `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` on `_ImageSliderState` scaffold. Because default color of scaffold is grey[50](if I'm not wrong).

Comment: ok for spacing i can edit itt with some adjustment let me check for color and also yaa i provide bg color as grey

Answer (score 0):

wrap Column with SingleChildScrollView

`````dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
      child: SingleChildScrollView ( child:  Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/menu.svg",
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                child: Container(
                  width: _folded ? 52 : 250,
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(4, 0),
                        ),
                      ]),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                          child: !_folded
                              ? TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Search Book, Author,Genre ',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontFamily:
                                          GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: InkWell(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(32),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    _folded
                                        ? "assets/icons/search.svg"
                                        : "assets/icons/close1.svg",
                                    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(18),
                                    color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _folded = !_folded;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [ImageSlider()],
          )
        ],
      ),),
    );
  } ````
`````

Comment: what is the initial height of the AnimatedContainer

Comment: it takes full screen

Answer (score 0):

```html
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';


class AutopayCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const AutopayCarousel({
    super.key,
    required this.store,
  });

  @override
  State<AutopayCarousel> createState() => _AutopayCarouselState();
}

class _AutopayCarouselState extends State<AutopayCarousel> {
  @override
 

  ***** double inComingWidgetHeight = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Observer(
      builder: (context) => Visibility(
        visible: widget.store.pendingMandateList.isNotEmpty,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: theme.spacing.s4),
              child: fskit_ux.FinHeaderSection(
                headerTitle: widget.configuration.autopayRequestHeader,
              ),
            ),
            CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: widget.store.pendingMandateList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index, _) {
                final mandateInfo = widget.store.pendingMandateList[index];
        


               *********************

                return   Column(
                  children: [                       
                     WidgetSize(
                      onSizeDecided: (size) {
                        setState(() {
                          inComingWidgetHeight = size.height;
                        });
                      },
                      child: YourWidget(--------),
                    ),
                     *****


                  ],
                );
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
      
                ***** height: inComingWidgetHeight, *****

                viewportFraction: kSingleViewportFraction,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                  widget.store.updateCarouselActiveIndex(index);
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: theme.sizing.s4),
            Center(
              child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                activeIndex: widget.store.carouselActiveIndex,
                count: widget.store.pendingMandateList.length,
                effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                  dotHeight: theme.sizing.half,
                  dotWidth: theme.sizing.base,
                  spacing: theme.sizing.base,
                  expansionFactor: theme.sizing.s4,
                  activeDotColor: theme.color.onBackgroundHighContrast,
                  dotColor: theme.color.onBackgroundHighContrast.withOpacity(
                    theme.opacity.o60,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: theme.sizing.s4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

=================================================

Wrap your IncomingWidget with Column widget and then inside column with the help of WidgetSize() you can find incomingWidgetHeight size.